# using fingerprint Reader dll import

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use Hikvision fingerprint reader sdk it seems simple but I need help on how to send parameters

```
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct FP_IMAGE_DATA
        {
            public int dwWidth;
            public int dwHeight;
            public byte[] pbyImage;
        }
public enum FP_MSG_TYPE_T
        {
            FP_MSG_PRESS_FINGER,
            FP_MSG_RISE_FINGER,
            FP_MSG_ENROLL_TIME,
            FP_MSG_CAPTURED_IMAGE,
        }
public delegate void FpMessageHandler(FP_MSG_TYPE_T enMsgType, IntPtr pMsgData);
[DllImport("FPModule_SDK.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int FPModule_InstallMessageHandler(FpMessageHandler msgHandler);
```

Can you give me information on how to use the FPModule_InstallMessageHandler ?

I'm not sure what to do

Comment: 'public delegate void FpMessageHandler(FP_MSG_TYPE_T enMsgType, IntPtr pMsgData);' I need to create a structure for the method but I have no idea how to do it.